# Standalone Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

Can Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing be used without the Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing.All package? The description recommends the All package, but is it possible to use Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not recommend using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing standalone, but it is possible. The .All package includes native Windows Performance Toolkit binaries required to run TraceProcessor, but if you have the right version of WPT already installed somewhere, it is possible to force TraceProcessor to use that version instead.

Note that you'll need to handle picking the right bitness yourself as well as ensuring that it's the correct, supported WPT version, which is why we generally do not recommend this approach. Here's what it would look like:

```cs
TraceProcessorSettings settings = new TraceProcessorSettings
{
    ToolkitPath = @"X:\path\to\correct\WindowsPerformanceToolkit"
};

using (ITraceProcessor trace = TraceProcessor.Create(tracePath, settings))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can one also install the msi directly? I have issues with first time call because I have added multi processes due to the single thread nature of the library. and now the first install will fail due to concurrent installation tries

Comment: It's possible, but it's probably a bit tricky to get right. I'd recommend letting TraceProcessor do that for you - perhaps have a single well-known trace file you use single-threaded to get things installed, and then run parallel after that.

Comment: I have opened a not existing ETL file with TraceProcessor.Create("notexisting.etl") with try catch around it from the main process before it spawns child processes. That has solved the issue nicely.